# Another word for man-of-all-work

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for another word for the phrase in a crossword puzzle " man-of-all-work. 8 letters to include these blank A blank T blank T blank M. Can you help?

Comment: http://www3.oneacross.com/cgi-bin/search_word.cgi?w=FACTOTUM&c=work

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about filling in a crossword clue.

Comment: @mplungjan - how the heck did you figure *that* out?! (OK, just figured it out. Cool.)

Answer (score 3):

Use this tool: http://www.ojohaven.com/fun/crossword.html

To get this word: **factotum**

> *noun* (plural ***factotums***)
>
> an employee who does all kinds of work:
>   *he was employed as the general factotum*
>
> > mid 16th century (originally in the phrases *dominum* (or *magister*) *factotum*, translating roughly as 'master of everything', and *Johannes factotem* [sic] 'John do-it-all' or 'Jack of all trades'): from medieval Latin, from Latin *fac!* 'do!' (imperative of *facere*) + *totum* 'the whole thing' (neuter of *totus*)
>
> [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/factotum)

Comment: Beat me by 9 secs

Comment: So much for all the gophers and handymen of the world! PS: I’d give the etymology so the word makes sense.

Comment: @tchrist: Speaking of, the built-in dictionary in OS X has an interesting little typo in its brief etymology, claiming that earlier examples include _Johannes factotem_. It translates that as ‘John do-it-all’, but I suppose a more exact translation would be ‘John, make a totem!’.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The ***X*-it-all** formulations, starting with a *know-it-all*, are common enough. With English morphology it’s harder to pin down the original verbal inflection (“Inflection, what inflection?” :), but in other languages we see different patterns. Compared Spanish *sabelotodo* (“know-it-all”), not to mention [*hacelotodo*, *vendelotodo*, *comelotodo*](http://trobandovoy.blogspot.com/2010/07/los-hacelotodo-los-vendelotodo-los.html). Here you can distinguish 2p imperative from 3p indicative only in *hacelodo*, which would be the “irregular” **hazlotodo* were it imperative.

Comment: @tchrist Etymology added.

Comment: @tchrist, in ‘factotum’, though, you can quite clearly see the original verbal inflection, too: _fac_ is unambiguously 2sg imperative of _facere_, whereas 3sg indicative would be _facit_ (third-declension names like _Johannes_ don’t have a vocative, so no distinction there). Andrew, I see the typo originates with ODO!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet So it does. Added [sic].

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes, I realize that.